# How to pass 2 types of value using http to strut action

Tags: java, jquery, angularjs, struts

I am using strut actions and want to pass one object and one text using $http of angularJS and to strut action class.

```
var applicationFlow = $('#txtApplicationFlow').val();
//alert(applicationFlow);
var primaryUserDetails ={
    firstName: $scope.txtFirstName,
    middleName:$scope.txtMiddleName,
    lastName:  $scope.txtLastName,
    familyCode:$scope.stFamilyCode,
    add1:      $scope.stSenderAdd1,
    add2:      $scope.stSenderAdd2,
    add3:      $scope.stSenderAdd3,
    city:      $scope.stSenderCity,
    state:     $scope.state,
    zipCode:   $scope.stZipCode,
    country:   $scope.country,
    phoneNo:   $scope.txtPhoneNo,
    emailID:   $scope.txtEmailId,
    rName:     $scope.txtRitvikName,
    rActive:   $scope.chkIsDecessed,
    pwd:       $scope.stPassword
};
//var contextPath = "addPrimaryUser.do"+"?primaryUserDetails="+ JSON.stringify(priaryUserDetails)+"&applicationFlow="+applicationFlow;
var contextPath = "addPrimaryUser.do"+"?primaryUserDetails="+ priaryUserDetails+"&applicationFlow="+applicationFlow;
$http({
    method : "POST",
    url : contextPath,
    data: primaryUserDetails
}).then ..........
```

How to pass applicationFlow  and primaryUserDetails  at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass it inside request body, that means `data` property of `$http` call, not in the `URL` as in query parameter.

```
var contextPath = "addPrimaryUser.do"
$http({
    method : "POST",
    url : contextPath,
    data: {
       primaryUserDetails: primaryUserDetails,
       applicationFlow: applicationFlow
    }
}).then(...)
```

OR

```
var contextPath = "addPrimaryUser.do"
$http.post(contextPath, {
   primaryUserDetails: primaryUserDetails,
   applicationFlow: applicationFlow
}).then(...)
```

Only make sure your strut action have `primaryUserDetails` & `applicationFlow` present inside a model (I mean case of variable names should match)